# Grayscale filter stops image overlay from displaying

Tags: jquery, css, filter, overlay, grayscale

I'm having trouble with filters and jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseenter(function(){
    $("overlay").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
    $('img').addClass("gray");
    });
    $("overlay").mouseleave(function (){
    $("img").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
    });
}); 

.gray {
  filter: grayscale(1);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(1);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1)
}

#g1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}



 <div id="g1">
    Some text to go on overlay<br/>
<a href="#">READ MORE</a>
    </div>
<img alt="" src="/portals/197/gfm/gb1.jpg" width="100%">
```

So on hover I want the overlay to show with the text/button and the image behind the overlay to be grayscale. But the Grayscale seems to be blocking the overlay from displaying.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Check this updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/sc4vwwyc/11/)

First of all try to use image overlay like this way,

**HTML**

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/200" >
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block
}   

.img-wrapper:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:0; 
    top:0;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 
}
```

Comment: Heya, thanks for your answer i didn't really explain myself fully i guess, I've just edited my post so you can see the text and button that go on the overlay on hover. So when you hover the image greyscale and the overlay slides down with text and the button on it. (hopefully im making sense)

Comment: Thanks heaps, thats an brilliant way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This below code adds `grayscale` effect on your image when `mouseleave` and `mouseenter`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).addClass("gray");
    });
    $("img").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("gray");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i just cant get it to add a class as well as the overlay to slide down with the text/button at the same time.

Comment: @MrWeb Then your class gray-scale won't be visible. It hides back of overlay class.

Comment: You can see it due to the overlay being transparent

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i was doing wrong, The JQ was just written out of order.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".g1").mouseenter(function(){
        $('.g1').addClass("gray");
        $("#g1").show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
});
        $("#g1").mouseleave(function (){
        $('.g1').removeClass("gray");
        $("#g1").hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 600);
        });
});
```

This works fine now =)